# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined in chart js in yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii2-basic-app

I am using yii2 basic. I have integrated Admin LTE

Now I am also using Chart js to show statistical data using chart through database data.

I have data.php storing containing database data code as follows:

data.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "shgreportingdatabase";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    //die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//echo "Connected successfully";



$sql = "SELECT employee.FirstName, count(*) as TotalGroups from groupdetails, employee WHERE groupdetails.EmpId=employee.EmpId group by groupdetails.EmpId";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result!=null) {
    // output data of each row
   $data = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
    }
} 
$conn->close();

print json_encode($data);
```

An output of data:

```
 { 
     [0]=> array(2) 
         { 
             ["FirstName"]=> string(5) "Silas" 
             ["TotalGroups"]=> string(1) "3" 
         } 
     [1]=> array(2) 
        { 
             ["FirstName"]=> string(4) "Nick"
             ["TotalGroups"]=> string(1) "4"
        } 
    [2]=> array(2) 
       { 
            ["FirstName"]=> string(7) "Joshuva" 
            ["TotalGroups"]=> string(1) "2" 
       } 
   [3]=> array(2) 
       { 
            ["FirstName"]=> string(6) "Ashish"
            ["TotalGroups"]=> string(1) "1"
       } 
}
```

I have a Groupdetails CRUD. In views folder, for Groupdetails, I have created datachart.php containing code for chart as shown below.

datachart.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use app\models\Employee;
use app\models\Groupdetails;
use app\models\Church;
use app\models\Courses;
$this->title = 'Reports';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Dashboard</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css">
  <!-- Morris chart -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/morris/morris.css">
  <!-- jvectormap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">
  <!-- Date Picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css">
  <!-- Daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
  <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>


  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
            #chart-container {
                width: 500px;
                height: auto;
            } 
        </style>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->

    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
    <?php
      if(\Yii::$app->user->can('admin'))
      {
      ?>
      <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->  

          <canvas id="barChart" width="100" height="50"></canvas>



        <!-- javascript -->

      <?php
      }
        ?>

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/chartexample/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var emp = [];
            var groups = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                emp.push(" " +data[i].FirstName);
                groups.push(data[i].TotalGroups);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: emp,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'SHG Groups',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 200)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: groups
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata,
                options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I run this, no chart is displayed. If I inspect the code, in console I can see the data coming through json, but chart is not displayed and also foll exception is displayed:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
    at i (Chart.min.js:10)
    at new e (Chart.min.js:10)
    at Object.success (index.php?r=groupdetails/datachart:278)
    at fire (jquery.js:3187)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3317)
    at done (jquery.js:8757)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9123)
```

Comment: Can you include  `var_dump($data)` output?

Comment: In datachart.php file?

Comment: Yes, that file, or an example of console.log(data)

Comment: It gives following output:                                                                  
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["FirstName"]=>
    string(5) "Silas"
    ["TotalGroups"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["FirstName"]=>
    string(4) "Nick"
    ["TotalGroups"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["FirstName"]=>
    string(7) "Joshuva"
    ["TotalGroups"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["FirstName"]=>
    string(6) "Ashish"
    ["TotalGroups"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}

Comment: Does the chart render if you hardcode values into `groups[]` ?